# What library and what version of XSLT does Solr 7.6 install for use with the response writer?

Tags: xslt, solr, xslt-2.0

I've written an XSL to transform my XML response from Solr 7.6.  The XSL is version 2.  It works fine if I apply it to the pure XML response using [Oxygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com), but when I reference it in the query string using `wt=xslt&rt=my.xsl`, it errors out.  The example.xsl shipped with Solr works, so my configuration is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the version of XSLT dynamically is easy via [`system-property('xsl:version')`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#function-system-property).

`system-property('xsl:vendor')` will return the XSLT processor being used.